# How to check the amount that will scroll and modify the amount?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

I'd like to know exactly how many pixels the content will scroll before it actually scrolls and adjust based on circumstances.

```
$(window).on('wheel', function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});

$(window).scroll(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
});
```

How can I get the amount that will be scrolled in pixels and then scroll a different amount before the actual scroll happens?

Comment: do you mean a scrollable area inside the scrollable document's body?

Comment: Basically it's a div inside the body which holds all the content that I would like to control scroll.

Comment: check edited and demo. if not what you need, then should be as good a start as possible. Other than a scroll plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to calculate this, here's what I use. Lets say we have an element that is 200px tall and has 1000px of content; `$(el)[0].scrollHeight` is the amount of scrollable content, `$(element)[0].scrollTop` is how much of the scrollable content has been scrolled and is above the element's "viewport".

How much it can be scrolled:

```
var scrollablePixels = $(element)[0].scrollHeight - $(element).scrollTop(); // 1000px
```

if it has been fully scrolled, the following will return true:

```
var hasScrolledToBottom = $(element)[0].scrollHeight - $(element).scrollTop() === $(element).height(); // false -- hasn't been scrolled yet
```

set the amount scrolled:

```
var pixelsToScrollElement = $(element).scrollTop(800);
```

now let's run the `hasScrolledToBottom` test again

```
$(element)[0].scrollHeight - $(element).scrollTop() === $(element).height(); // true
```

## edit

An answer to another post will help: [IN VIEWPORT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport#answer-15203639)

basically you can use a combination of what I've listed and what's posted there to make your calculations

## edit 3

## [DEMO](http://codepen.io/presstep/pen/e5648919a8e2dfd9ae239ec0482b5a06)

```
window.onmousewheel = document.onmousewheel = customScroll;

function customScroll(e) {
    var scrollTime = 1200,
        scrollDistance = 200,
        wheelChange = e.wheelDelta ? e.wheelDelta / 120 
                            : e.detail ? -e.detail / 3
                                       : 0,
        scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop() - scrollDistance * wheelChange;

    $('html, body').stop().animate({
        scrollTop: scrollTop
    }, scrollTime);

    e.preventDefault();
    e.returnValue = false;
}

$(window).on('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    customScroll(e);
});
```

Comment: I'm trying to obtain the amount that will scroll before it scrolls and modify the value.

Comment: do you mean "when it is in the viewport"?

Comment: Yes, when it's visible.

Comment: follow the link i included in my edit for this solution

Comment: I don't see how that link is relevant? I'm just trying to change the scroll amount when the scroll event happens.

Comment: ok onscroll, $('#myDiv').css('transform', 'translateY('+$(window).scrollTop() / scrollFactor 'px)');

Comment: scrollFactor == how many times faster you want the window to scroll than your div

Comment: does that help? if so I'll change my answer.

Comment: Basically when a scroll happens, I'd like to hijack what would normally happen and change the amount it would scroll, etc. The usual scroll should not happen at all. From a user standpoint it should be seamless.

Comment: So apply that answer to a `positioned` wrapper div. $('#myWrapper').css('transform', 'translateY('+$(window).scrollTop() / scrollFactor 'px)');

Comment: I don't see how your answer would work. I'd like to cancel out the previous scroll that would happen by default and then I may or may not move it an arbitrary amount.

Comment: lol. dude. It's like I'm getting more of your question every time I anwser "it"

Comment: Sorry, maybe I'm not very smart. Thanks for the thorough reply!

Comment: I chose your answer but what's the default pixel amount the browser would scroll on mousewheel usage? How can I allow the default to happen?

Answer (score 0):

The scroll event fires after scrolling takes place so that's not possible.

Comment: why not `$element.scroll()`?

Comment: That would trigger a scroll event. Not side if that is what @rotaercz wants. Personally I would not mess with things like scrolling.

Comment: @Matjis agreed, not a fan of UX hijacking. Interested in the intellectual, problem-solving part of it only. You made a reasonable argument, definitely not downvote-worthy, but didn't offer any details. I wanted readers of this answer know that they could trigger programmatically, say after attaching evt handler: `$(el).scroll(function(e) { ... }).scroll();` I'm still not sure I understand what the OP wants...